# Protocol being reset in cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, protocols

I have a cell with a textField and a button. The button opens a page to collect data and has a protocol to pass that data back to the cell and fill the textField. That all works fine, however, when I come back the value is reset to zero. Print statements show that it is passing the data when it's set, but hitting `Back` clears it for some reason.

Protocol

```
protocol DistanceProtocol {
    func distanceSet(distance: Double)
}
```

Call to protocol method

```
distanceProtocol?.distanceSet(totalDistance)
```

Cell class

```
class InputCell: CalculatorCell, DistanceProtocol {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField?

    private var inputType = InputType.undefined

    var viewController = UIViewController()

    override func getHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return 90
    }

    func distanceSet(distance: Double) {
        print(distance)
        textField?.text = "\(distance)"
    }

    func getInputType() -> InputType {
        return inputType
    }

    func setInputType(inputType: InputType) {
        self.inputType = inputType
    }

    @IBAction func walkTouched(sender: UIButton) {
        let mapVc = viewController.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Map") as! MapLocationsViewController

        mapVc.distanceProtocol = self

        viewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(mapVc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, everything is set up correctly. It's not reloading the cells in the tableView when I come back. Why is it resetting/how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

the text field is only set when you call the function. Unless you call this function in cellForRowAtIndex path it wont retain the value

I would likely implement it using a setter, do everytime the value is set, the label gets updated

```
protocol DistanceProtocol {
    func distanceSet(distance: Double)
}

class CellWithText: UITableViewCell {

    var cellText: String {
       didSet {
           textLabel?.text = cellText
       }
    }

}

extension CellWithText: DistanceProtocol {
   func distanceSet(distance: Double) {
    self.cellText = "\(distance)"
   }
}
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath call you would call the function

```
cell.distanceSet(19.0)
```

Comment: I can't call the method from cellForRow. The tableView is the controller that's supposed to be receiving the distance, so it wouldn't know what the distance is.

Comment: so how are you currently trying to set the cell text? if your tableView has this value, its fairly easy to pass to the cell. I think you need to provide additonal code

Comment: I have edited the original question, adding in the entire cell class. Please let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 0):

i think you might try singleton design pattern or you can use struct for copying.